# How to shorten text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, react-native

I am trying to reduce the length of the text that I have requested from

the API with the 'slice' method. but it is throwing an error of

'Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined.

[image]

[image]

Comment: also [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` means that your `jobDetails.job_description` property is not of type string, but of type undefined at runtime. Make sure you have that property at least defined as an empty string.